# How to get the open/unresolved cases on SFDC report?

Tags: community, reporting, custom-report-type, analytics

I want list all open and unresolved cases by the time of Sep. 30. The problem is when I list it now, all the cases that are opened and unresolved before Sep. 30 are closed now. Is there any way I can list all the cases Open/unresolved by the end of Sep. 30.  I mean filter.

I know, for the filter,

**Created Date less than or equal to  9/30/2015**

I having hard time to figure out the rest.

Can anybody please help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to add the Closed Date field as a filter. It will look like this:

**Created Date less than or equal to 9/30/2015**

**Closed Date greater than 9/30/2015**

You may need to adjust your filters slightly depending on the exact *time* you care about, but this should give you a good start.